# MPI_Barrier in different threads, behaviour?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, mpi

Lets say I have 2 processes each with two threads (**1 IO thread**, 1 compute thread)

I am interessted in using some IO library (adios).
**I am asking me what will happend if I would code something like this?:**

- lets say the IO threads in the 2 processes do some IO and they use
  `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)` at some point **B**  to synchronize the
  IO!
- the compute threads in the two processes also use the `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)` at some point **A** to synchronize the computation (while the IO threads are working).

---> I dont know exactly what might happen, is the following case possible:

- Process 1, IO Thread waits at **B**
- Process 2, Compute thread waits at **A**

=> and Process 1 and 2 get synchronized (so Process 1 leaves barrier at **B** and process 2 at **A** (also process 2 has not the same point where it synchronizes!)

If that might happen, isn't this an unwanted behavior which was not intended by the programmer. (Can that be avoided by using two different communicator with identical number of processes (`MPI_Comm_dup(...)` ) ?

Or is the barrier really code line dependent? But how is this realized if true so?

This is confusing!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first scenario is very likely to happen (barrier calls from different threads matching each other). From MPI's point of view a barrier must be entered by all **ranks** inside the communicator, no matter from which thread comes the barrier call and at which code line the call is. MPI still has no notion of thread identity and all threads are treated together as a single entity - a rank. The only special treatment is that when the `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` thread support level is being provided, the library should implement proper locks so that MPI calls could be made from any thread and at any time.

That's why it is highly advisable that parallel library authors should always duplicate the world communicator and use the duplicate for internal communication needs. That way the library code won't interfere with the user code (with some special exceptions that could result in deadlocks).